# Is it an idiomatic expression, "in a very near future"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, idiomatic-language

Oxford Dictionary (https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/just) gives a bunch of definitions about “just”

one of those is

> 1.1 Exactly or almost exactly at this or that moment

and gives this example

> ‘she's just coming’

To help understand this piece of meaning, I would like to consider that as "in a very near future"?

Is it an idiomatic expression, "in a very near future"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We would normally say "in **the** [very] near future", because ordinarily we assume there is only one future.  Saying "a future" implies there are a multitude of futures, which is a little bit sci-fi, although could possibly be used in some contexts where the speaker/writer wishes to emphasise that possibilities are still open.  For example we might say "In a future where the economy is based on renewable energy..." to emphasise there are other likely futures where that is not the case.  But in the example of "she's just coming" however this would not really apply, as we know she *is* coming.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does a pair of brackets in "in the [very] near future" mean the word "very" is optional?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 2):

It would be "in *the* very near future", because there is only one future.

With the correct article, yes it is idiomatic, a common phrase.

I'm not sure what connection you are making to the use of "just" though. We use "just" when talking about time to show that something is happening *now*. Saying someone is "just coming" means they are on their way, travelling to you at this moment. Their *arrival* could be said to be "in the very near future", although the most natural thing would be to say "soon". "In the very near future" sounds overly dramatic for everyday things like when someone will arrive.